# Use Excel formula to highlight chosen value from first sheet on the second sheet if matches

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, find

Is it possible to highlight chosen value from first sheet on the second sheet if matches?
For example, I click on the cell with the value "Map" on the first sheet, and Excel switches to the second sheet in the workbook and automatically place the cursor on the cell with the same value if there is a match.

Comment: You can do everything with VBA. What have you tried already?

Comment: Conditional formatting can help you highlight the cell but cannot place the cursor on the cell....

Answer (score 0):

you can use the macro below if it solves your puzzle.
You can create a keyboard shortcut for this macro and each time you run the macro, it will search for the selected text in the very next (right) sheet in your excel file.  You can edit macro according to your needs.

```
Sub Macro4()
    my_text = Selection.Value
    ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    Cells.Select
    On Error GoTo my_err
    Selection.Find(What:=my_text, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Exit Sub
my_err: MsgBox "search text not found"
    ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
    
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Roman, my answer above is kind of a ready-to-use solution to your problem.  For your possible future queries, I recommend you to start coding in VBA as commented by harrymc.  A good way to start could be recording a macro in excel and then analysing the codes in the macro.

Comment: How to start briefly: Click on record macro button in developer toolbar, perform your copy/paste/find/delete/etc operations, then stop your macro. Then hit Alt + F8, select your macro and click on edit. Analyse the codes excel recorded and try to improve them according to your needs (i.e. if you will use it regularly, make adjustments accordingly.  You will need to define variables/constants/arrays and get to know software things like do loop, for next, if then etc.). When you got stuck you can do a quick google search and after all if you still need help, you can ask another question here.